# Adding a Privacy Option

Tags: contacts, privacy

For the contact field Communication Preferences> Privacy

How difficult would it be to add a new option "Do Not Voicemail"

One of our clients is a counselling service. So this would be useful for them.

They have a stopgap solution usign other custom data fields- but this is in a separate section of the record to the communications info.

What is the process for making requests for this kind of amendment in core?

Is anyone able to pitch a rough cost?

Would this feature be useful to anyone else?

If I can get the client's approval I can look at the Make It Happen process.

Comment: Maybe not an exact answer but there is a "Voicemail" phone type that suggests that that would be the phone to use for voicemail, so the rule could be that if the phone type is not voicemail then don't leave a message. I've seen it used this way. You could make it more explicit by relabelling the location and phone types as needed.

Comment: A useful suggestion. Will pass back to client. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You could do this fairly easily with the [Contact Layout Editor](https://civicrm.org/extensions/contact-layout-editor) extension (assuming you're on CiviCRM 5.x).

- Use the extension to remove the existing Communication Preferences block from the Summary page.
- Build a custom block that includes the normal communication preferences fields plus "Do Not Voicemail".
- You'll probably want to remove "Do Not Voicemail" from the custom field block in a similar manner so it doesn't appear twice.

Comment: Thanks Jon.

Will bear this in mind, and discuss with client. Bit wary of doing this through an extension/ customisation. One good future update can cause problems.

Will update my initial question to be more explicit.

Comment: The extension is well-supported and written by a member of the CiviCRM core team - but more importantly, it only affects the form level.  In the (very unlikely) event that the extension has a catastrophic failure, you simply disable it, and the field is back where it is now with no data loss.

Comment: Thanks Jon, that is reassuring to know. Our client has seen your original suggestion and is interested in going ahead.